# Will Heroku time out a request if it sits in the queue for too long?

Tags: heroku, timeout, queue

I have a Rails app running on Heroku. I'm expecting a big spike in traffic tomorrow. I know I can temporarily scale up the dynos if need be to support the traffic.

What happens if there is a spike in traffic and requests are sitting in the queue for too long? Is there a max size to the queue and/or do requests timeout? And if a request times out in the queue, what page shows up and how do I customize that page? (or would that be ERROR_PAGE_URL?)